# philosophers dining

Tags: c, pthreads

so Im trying to solve the philosophers dining problem with some semaphores..
when I compile it I get philosophers1-5 are thinking,phisopher 1 is hungry he takes fork 
5 and 1,philosopher 3 is hungry and then the program stops  there...I dont know wheres the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define N 5
#define THINKING 0
#define HUNGRY 1
#define EATING 2
#define LEFT (i+4)%N
#define RIGHT (i+1)%N


sem_t mutex;
sem_t S[N];  
void * philospher(void *num);
void take_fork(int);
void put_fork(int);
void test(int);

int state[N];
int phil_num[N]={0,1,2,3,4};

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t thread_id[N];
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        sem_init(&S[i],0,1);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,philospher,(void *)i);
        printf("Philosopher %d is thinking\n",i+1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL);
}


void *philospher(void *num)
 {
    while(1)
    {
        int i;
      i = (int)num;
        sleep(1);
        //take_fork(i);


    sem_wait(&mutex);
    state[i] = HUNGRY;
    printf("Philosopher %d is Hungry\n",i+1);
     //test(i);


    if (state[i] == HUNGRY && state[LEFT] != EATING && state[RIGHT] != EATING)
    {
        sem_wait(&S[LEFT]);
        sem_wait(&S[RIGHT]);
        state[i] = EATING;
        sleep(2);
        printf("Philosopher %d takes fork %d and %d\n",i+1,LEFT+1,i+1);
        printf("Philosopher %d is Eating\n",i+1);
    }

    sem_post(&mutex);
    sleep(1);


        //put_fork(*i);


    sem_wait(&mutex);
    state[i] = THINKING;
    printf("Philosopher %d putting fork %d and %d down\n",i+1,LEFT+1,i+1);
    printf("Philosopher %d is thinking\n",i+1);
    sem_post(&S[LEFT]);
    sem_post(&S[RIGHT]);
    //test(LEFT);
    //test(RIGHT);
    sem_post(&mutex);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: when I compile it theres nothing wrong.But when i run it printing some results but then the program pauses?(not sure if thats the correct word) for some kind of reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a race condition.

You're referring to `state[RIGHT]` in the worker function, but there's no guarantee that all threads have been created so that the `state` array is initialized at that point.

Comment: But the threads have nothing to do with the state.I mean that when the if condition is testing if he can take the forks it is testing between the state array and not with the threads.